# I have two lists A and B when i change A it change also at B how i prevent this?

Tags: python

I have two lists A and B when i change A it change also at B how i prevent this?

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5]
B = A
A.append(6)

print(A)
print(B)
```

thank's for the help.

Comment: You have only one list with two names.

Answer (score 0):

You have one list, and two variables pointing to it.

To make `B` point to a *copy* of `A`, you can use `B = list(A)`.